# Range of hours in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have this fullcalendar calendar to organize the work. The problem is that instead of appearing 24 hours a day, I only see the range of dates that I want, but no matter how much I look at the documentation, I don't see the way (I haven't been programming for long and I still get a little lost) . Can you tell me how the hours that go out are "limited"?

this is how it looks now:

[image]

and that's how I want it to look (Adjusting the space, of course):

[image]

mi código:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario1');
            var taller = '<?php echo $tare;?>'
            var user = '<?php echo $ctrl_user;?>'
            var userfiltro = '0'
  calendario1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  //let calendario1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(document.getElementById('Calendario1'), {   
    timeZone: 'local',
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    locale: 'es',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Trabajadores',
    resources: 'datoseventos.php?accion=listarempleados&taller=' + taller + '&user=' + user + '&user_filtro=' +userfiltro,
    //resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
   events: 'testurl.php?accion=listar&taller=' + taller + '&user=' + user + '&user_filtro=' +userfiltro,
dateClick: function(info) {
                console.log("ES "+JSON.stringify(info));
                 limpiarFormulario();
                    $('#BotonAgregar').show();
                    $('#BotonModificar').hide();
                    $('#BotonOt').hide();
                    $('#BotonBorrar').hide();
                    $('#iduser').val(info.resource.id);
                    if (info.allDay) {
                        $('#FechaInicio').val(info.dateStr);
                        $('#FechaFin').val(info.dateStr);
                    } else {
                        let fechaHora = info.dateStr.split("T");
                        var horainit = fechaHora[1].substring(0, 5);
                        var horafin = (parseInt(horainit) + parseInt(1))+":00";
                        $('#FechaInicio').val(fechaHora[0]);
                        $('#FechaFin').val(fechaHora[0]);
                        $('#HoraInicio').val(fechaHora[1].substring(0, 5));
                        $('#HoraFin').val(horafin);
                    }
                    $("#FormularioEventos").modal();
                },
                eventClick: function(info) {
                    console.log("EL RES ES "+JSON.stringify(info.event));
                    console.log("LA HORA ES "+moment(info.event.start).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#BotonModificar').show();
                    if (info.event.extendedProps.idtra != 0) {
                        if (info.event.extendedProps.tipo_parte != 0) {
                            $('#BotonOt').attr("href", "./modifica_parte_contado.php?id=" + info.event.extendedProps.idtra).show();
                        } else {
                            $('#BotonOt').attr("href", "./modifica_parte_cia.php?id=" + info.event.extendedProps.idtra).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('#BotonOt').hide();
                    }
                    $('#BotonBorrar').show();
                    $('#BotonAgregar').hide();
                    $('#Codigo').val(info.event.id);
                    $('#iduser').val(info.event.extendedProps.iduser);
                    $('#idtra').val(info.event.idtra);
                    $('#Titulo').val(info.event.title);
                    $('#Descripcion').val(info.event.extendedProps.descripcion);
                    $('#FechaInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#FechaFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#HoraInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#HoraFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#ColorFondo').val(info.event.backgroundColor);
                    $('#ColorTexto').val(info.event.textColor);
                    $("#FormularioEventos").modal();
                },
                eventResize: function(info) {
                    $('#Codigo').val(info.event.id);

                    $('#Titulo').val(info.event.title);
                    $('#iduser').val(info.event.extendedProps.iduser);
                    $('#FechaInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#FechaFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#HoraInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#HoraFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#ColorFondo').val(info.event.backgroundColor);
                    $('#ColorTexto').val(info.event.textColor);
                    $('#Descripcion').val(info.event.extendedProps.descripcion);
                    let registro = recuperarDatosFormulario();
                    modificarRegistro(registro);
                },
                eventDrop: function(info) {
                    $('#Codigo').val(info.event.id);
                    $('#Titulo').val(info.event.title);
                    $('#iduser').val(info.event.extendedProps.iduser);
                    $('#FechaInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#FechaFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#HoraInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#HoraFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#ColorFondo').val(info.event.backgroundColor);
                    $('#ColorTexto').val(info.event.textColor);
                    $('#Descripcion').val(info.event.extendedProps.descripcion);
                    let registro = recuperarDatosFormulario();
                    modificarRegistro(registro);
                },
                drop: function(info) {
                    limpiarFormulario();
                    $('#ColorFondo').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.colorfondo);
                    $('#ColorTexto').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.colortexto);
                    $('#Titulo').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.titulo);
                    let fechaHora = info.dateStr.split("T");
                    $('#FechaInicio').val(fechaHora[0]);
                    $('#FechaFin').val(fechaHora[0]);
                    $('#tiempocita').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.tiempocita);
                    if (info.allDay) { //verdadero si el calendario esta en vista de mes
                        $('#HoraInicio').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.horainicio);
                        $('#HoraFin').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.horafin);
                    } else {
                        $('#HoraInicio').val(fechaHora[1].substring(0, 5));
                        $('#HoraFin').val(moment(fechaHora[1].substring(0, 5)).add(1, 'hours'));
                    }
                    let registro = recuperarDatosFormulario();
                    agregarEventoPredefinido(registro);
                }
  });

  calendario1.render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use fullcalendar's View API **[slotMinTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotMinTime)** and **[slotMaxTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotMaxTime)**

```
resourceTimelineDay: {
 slotMinTime: "07:00:00",
 slotMaxTime: "12:00:00",
}
```

This should work for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it worked like this:

```
    views:{
      resourceTimelineMonth:{
        duration: { days:7 },
        slotDuration:'24:00:00'
      },
      resourceTimelineWeek:{
        duration: { days:7 },
        slotDuration:'24:00:00'
      },
      resourceTimelineDay:{
        duration: { days:1 },
        slotMinTime: "09:00:00",
        slotMaxTime: "19:00:00",
      }
    },
```

Comment: Nice, hope I was helpful